# Run a HTTP server in MySQL to receive data from a client

Tags: c++, mysql, http, httpserver

I want to insert a Json content from android cell phone (as client) into my MySQL database (in server). In order that, at first, I send this Json content from my client to my server which runs a HTTP server using Qt application in C++. Next in C++, I call a MySQL stored procedure to insert the received Json into my database. As we see, there is an interface in C++ (HTTP Server) which I'm going to omit it.

I want to know, is there an approach like running HTTP server in MySQL to handle the above process without a HTTP server in C++? (So I can send the Json content from my client to my MySQL database directly.)

Comment: http is a protocol to transport webpages. tcp is a transportprotocol. But it doesn't matter how you transport the data, which are only bytes, abd your application iterprets these data and makes them again into json.  So you need always a server entity to accept bytes and this can be a webserver. The problem on endeffect is, are you willing to put a mysql server open to the wild internet. usually the answer is no, also you should check if your c++ program is secure enough not to be compromised and endanger your how system

Answer (score 3):

No, the MYSQL server does not expose a JSON interface. You'd have to interact with the MSQL server directly using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/package-summary). So no JSON, but direct SQL queries to your MYSQL server.

If you don't want to do that, a http webserver is not the only option, but it's probably the most sensible solution.